# How to add sku to related products on Magento 2.4?

Tags: php, magento2.4.1

I would like to add the sku to the related products. How can I do that?

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

use Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Product\Listing\PreparePostData;
use Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface;

/* @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer $secureRenderer */
?>

<?php
switch ($type = $block->getType()) {

case 'related-rule':
    if ($exist = $block->hasItems()) {
        $type = 'related';
        $class = $type;

        $image = 'related_products_list';
        $title = __('Related Products');
        $items = $block->getAllItems();
        $limit = $block->getPositionLimit();
        $shuffle = (int) $block->isShuffled();
        $isWeightedRandom = (int) $block->getRotation()->isWeightedRandom($block->getProductListType());
        $canItemsAddToCart = $block->canItemsAddToCart();

        $showAddTo = true;
        $showCart = false;
        $templateType = null;
        $description = false;
    }
    break;

case 'related':
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related $block */
    if ($exist = $block->getItems()->getSize()) {
        $type = 'related';
        $class = $type;

        $image = 'related_products_list';
        $title = __('Related Products');
        $items = $block->getItems();
        $limit = 0;
        $shuffle = 0;
        $isWeightedRandom = 0;
        $canItemsAddToCart = $block->canItemsAddToCart();

        $showAddTo = true;
        $showCart = false;
        $templateType = null;
        $description = false;
    }
    break;

case 'upsell-rule':
    if ($exist = $block->hasItems()) {
        $type = 'upsell';
        $class = $type;

        $image = 'upsell_products_list';
        $title = __('We found other products you might like!');
        $items = $block->getAllItems();
        $limit = $block->getPositionLimit();
        $shuffle = (int) $block->isShuffled();
        $isWeightedRandom = (int) $block->getRotation()->isWeightedRandom($block->getProductListType());

        $showAddTo = false;
        $showCart = false;
        $templateType = null;
        $description = false;
        $canItemsAddToCart = false;
    }
    break;

case 'upsell':
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Upsell $block */
    if ($exist = count($block->getItemCollection()->getItems())) {
        $type = 'upsell';
        $class = $type;

        $image = 'upsell_products_list';
        $title = __('We found other products you might like!');
        $items = $block->getItemCollection()->getItems();
        $limit = $block->getItemLimit('upsell');
        $shuffle = 0;
        $isWeightedRandom = 0;

        $showAddTo = false;
        $showCart = false;
        $templateType = null;
        $description = false;
        $canItemsAddToCart = false;
    }
    break;

case 'crosssell-rule':
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Crosssell $block */
    if ($exist = $block->hasItems()) {
        $type = 'crosssell';
        $class = $type;

        $image = 'cart_cross_sell_products';
        $title = __('More Choices:');
        $items = $block->getItemCollection();

        $showAddTo = true;
        $showCart = true;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
        $description = false;
        $canItemsAddToCart = false;
    }
    break;

case 'crosssell':
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Crosssell $block */
    if ($exist = count($block->getItems())) {
        $type = 'crosssell';
        $class = $type;

        $image = 'cart_cross_sell_products';
        $title = __('More Choices:');
        $items = $block->getItems();

        $showAddTo = true;
        $showCart = true;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
        $description = false;
        $canItemsAddToCart = false;
    }
    break;

case 'new':
    if ($exist = $block->getProductCollection()) {
        $type = 'new';
        $mode = 'grid';
        $type = $type . ' ' . $mode;

        $class = 'widget' . ' ' . $type;

        $image = 'new_products_content_widget_grid';
        $title = __('New Products');
        $items = $exist;

        $showAddTo = true;
        $showCart = true;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
        $description = ($mode == 'list') ? true : false;
        $canItemsAddToCart = false;
    }
    break;

    default:
        $exist = null;
}
    $_item = null;
  ?>
```

```
<?php if ($type == 'related' || $type == 'upsell'):?>
    <?php if ($type == 'related'):?>
<div class="block <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($class) ?>"
 data-mage-init='{"relatedProducts":{"relatedCheckbox":".related.checkbox"}}'
 data-limit="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($limit) ?>"
 data-shuffle="<?= /* @noEscape */ $shuffle ?>"
 data-shuffle-weighted="<?= /* @noEscape */ $isWeightedRandom ?>">
<?php else:?>
<div class="block <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($class) ?>"
     data-mage-init='{"upsellProducts":{}}'
     data-limit="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($limit) ?>"
     data-shuffle="<?= /* @noEscape */ $shuffle ?>"
     data-shuffle-weighted="<?= /* @noEscape */ $isWeightedRandom ?>">
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php else:?>
    <div class="block <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($class) ?>">
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="block-title title">
            <strong id="block-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($class) ?>-heading" role="heading"
                    aria-level="2"><?= $block->escapeHtml($title) ?></strong>
        </div>
        <div class="block-content content" aria-labelledby="block-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($class) ?>-heading">
            <?php if ($type == 'related' && $canItemsAddToCart):?>
                <div class="block-actions">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Check items to add to the cart or')) ?>
                    <button type="button" class="action select"
                            data-role="select-all"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('select all')) ?></span></button>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="products wrapper grid products-grid products-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($type) ?>">
                <ol class="products list items product-items">
                    <?php foreach ($items as $_item):?>
                        <?php $available = ''; ?>
                        <?php if (!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable() && $type == 'related'):?>
                            <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()):?>
                                <?php $available = 'related-available'; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if ($type == 'related' || $type == 'upsell'):?>
                            <li class="item product product-item"
                            id="product-item_<?= /* @noEscape */ $_item->getId() ?>"
                            data-shuffle-group="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getPriority()) ?>" >
                            <?= /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderStyleAsTag(
                                'display:none;',
                                'li#product-item_' . $_item->getId()
                            ) ?>
                        <?php else:?>
                            <li class="item product product-item">
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <div class="product-item-info <?= /* @noEscape */ $available ?>">
                            <?= /* @noEscape */ '<!-- ' . $image . '-->' ?>
                            <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl($_item)) ?>"
                               class="product photo product-item-photo">
                                <?= $block->getImage($_item, $image)->toHtml() ?>
                            </a>
                            <div class="product details product-item-details">
                                <strong class="product name product-item-name"><a
                                            class="product-item-link"
                                            title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getName()) ?>"
                                            href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl($_item)) ?>">
                                        <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a>
                                </strong>

                                <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>

                                <?php if ($templateType):?>
                                    <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, $templateType) ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php if ($canItemsAddToCart && !$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable()
                                    && $type == 'related'):?>
                                    <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()):?>
                                        <div class="field choice related">
                                            <input
                                                type="checkbox"
                                                class="checkbox related"
                                                id="related-checkbox<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>"
                                                name="related_products[]"
                                                value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>" />
                                            <label class="label"
                                                   for="related-checkbox<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId())
                                                    ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php if ($showAddTo || $showCart):?>
                                    <?php // phpcs:disable ?>
                                    <div class="product actions product-item-actions">
                                        <?php if ($showCart):?>
                                            <div class="actions-primary">
                                            <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()):?>
                                                <?php if (!$_item->getTypeInstance()->isPossibleBuyFromList($_item)):?>
                                                    <button
                                                            class="action tocart primary"
                                                            data-mage-init='{"redirectUrl": {"url": "<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item)) ?>"}}' type="button" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Cart')) ?>">
                                                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span>
                                                    </button>
                                                <?php else :?>
                                                    <?php
                                                    /** @var $viewModel PreparePostData */
                                                    $viewModel = $block->getViewModel();
                                                    $postArray = $viewModel->getPostData(
                                                        $block->escapeUrl($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item)),
                                                        ['product' => $_item->getEntityId()]
                                                    );
                                                    $value = $postArray['data'][ActionInterface::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED];
                                                    ?>
                                                    <form data-role="tocart-form"
                                                          data-product-sku="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getSku()) ?>"
                                                          action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item)) ?>"
                                                          method="post">
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="product"
                                                               value="<?= /* @noEscape */ (int)$_item->getEntityId() ?>">
                                                        <input type="hidden"
                                                               name="<?= /* @noEscape */ ActionInterface::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED?>"
                                                               value="<?= /* @noEscape */ $value ?>">
                                                        <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                                                        <button type="submit"
                                                                title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Cart')) ?>"
                                                                class="action tocart primary">
                                                            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </form>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            <?php else:?>
                                                <?php if ($_item->getIsSalable()):?>
                                                    <div class="stock available">
                                                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('In stock')) ?></span>
                                                    </div>
                                                <?php else:?>
                                                    <div class="stock unavailable">
                                                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Out of stock')) ?></span>
                                                    </div>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>

                                        <?php if ($showAddTo):?>
                                            <div class="secondary-addto-links actions-secondary"
                                                 data-role="add-to-links">
                                                <?php if ($addToBlock = $block->getChildBlock('addto')):?>
                                                    <?= $addToBlock->setProduct($_item)->getChildHtml() ?>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php // phpcs:enable ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled() && $_item):?>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
                "catalogAddToCart": {
                    "product_sku": "<?= $block->escapeJs($_item->getSku()) ?>"
                }
            }
        }
        </script>
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php endif;?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im assuming you are wanting to display it on a per product level if that is correct then you can simply add. if you use the example provided i have included the ability to show on related/upsell/crosssell products

```
<?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getSku()) ?>
```

**Result**

```
<?php
/**
* Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
* See COPYING.txt for license details.
*/

use Magento\Catalog\ViewModel\Product\Listing\PreparePostData;
use Magento\Framework\App\ActionInterface;

/* @var $block \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\AbstractProduct */
/** @var \Magento\Framework\View\Helper\SecureHtmlRenderer $secureRenderer */
?>

<?php
switch ($type = $block->getType()) {

case 'related-rule':
    if ($exist = $block->hasItems()) {
        $type = 'related';
        $class = $type;

        $image = 'related_products_list';
        $title = __('Related Products');
        $items = $block->getAllItems();
        $limit = $block->getPositionLimit();
        $shuffle = (int) $block->isShuffled();
        $isWeightedRandom = (int) $block->getRotation()->isWeightedRandom($block->getProductListType());
        $canItemsAddToCart = $block->canItemsAddToCart();

        $showAddTo = true;
        $showSku = false;
        $showCart = false;
        $templateType = null;
        $description = false;
    }
    break;

case 'related':
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Related $block */
    if ($exist = $block->getItems()->getSize()) {
        $type = 'related';
        $class = $type;

        $image = 'related_products_list';
        $title = __('Related Products');
        $items = $block->getItems();
        $limit = 0;
        $shuffle = 0;
        $isWeightedRandom = 0;
        $canItemsAddToCart = $block->canItemsAddToCart();

        $showAddTo = true;
        $showSku = true;
        $showCart = false;
        $templateType = null;
        $description = false;
    }
    break;

case 'upsell-rule':
    if ($exist = $block->hasItems()) {
        $type = 'upsell';
        $class = $type;

        $image = 'upsell_products_list';
        $title = __('We found other products you might like!');
        $items = $block->getAllItems();
        $limit = $block->getPositionLimit();
        $shuffle = (int) $block->isShuffled();
        $isWeightedRandom = (int) $block->getRotation()->isWeightedRandom($block->getProductListType());

        $showAddTo = false;
        $showSku = false;
        $showCart = false;
        $templateType = null;
        $description = false;
        $canItemsAddToCart = false;
    }
    break;

case 'upsell':
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Upsell $block */
    if ($exist = count($block->getItemCollection()->getItems())) {
        $type = 'upsell';
        $class = $type;

        $image = 'upsell_products_list';
        $title = __('We found other products you might like!');
        $items = $block->getItemCollection()->getItems();
        $limit = $block->getItemLimit('upsell');
        $shuffle = 0;
        $isWeightedRandom = 0;

        $showAddTo = false;
        $showSku = false;
        $showCart = false;
        $templateType = null;
        $description = false;
        $canItemsAddToCart = false;
    }
    break;

case 'crosssell-rule':
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Crosssell $block */
    if ($exist = $block->hasItems()) {
        $type = 'crosssell';
        $class = $type;

        $image = 'cart_cross_sell_products';
        $title = __('More Choices:');
        $items = $block->getItemCollection();

        $showAddTo = true;
        $showCart = true;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
        $description = false;
        $canItemsAddToCart = false;
    }
    break;

case 'crosssell':
    /** @var \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ProductList\Crosssell $block */
    if ($exist = count($block->getItems())) {
        $type = 'crosssell';
        $class = $type;

        $image = 'cart_cross_sell_products';
        $title = __('More Choices:');
        $items = $block->getItems();

        $showAddTo = true;
        $showCart = true;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
        $description = false;
        $canItemsAddToCart = false;
    }
    break;

case 'new':
    if ($exist = $block->getProductCollection()) {
        $type = 'new';
        $mode = 'grid';
        $type = $type . ' ' . $mode;

        $class = 'widget' . ' ' . $type;

        $image = 'new_products_content_widget_grid';
        $title = __('New Products');
        $items = $exist;

        $showAddTo = true;
        $showCart = true;
        $templateType = \Magento\Catalog\Block\Product\ReviewRendererInterface::SHORT_VIEW;
        $description = ($mode == 'list') ? true : false;
        $canItemsAddToCart = false;
    }
    break;

    default:
        $exist = null;
}
    $_item = null;
  ?>




<?php if ($type == 'related' || $type == 'upsell'):?>
    <?php if ($type == 'related'):?>
<div class="block <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($class) ?>"
 data-mage-init='{"relatedProducts":{"relatedCheckbox":".related.checkbox"}}'
 data-limit="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($limit) ?>"
 data-shuffle="<?= /* @noEscape */ $shuffle ?>"
 data-shuffle-weighted="<?= /* @noEscape */ $isWeightedRandom ?>">
<?php else:?>
<div class="block <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($class) ?>"
     data-mage-init='{"upsellProducts":{}}'
     data-limit="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($limit) ?>"
     data-shuffle="<?= /* @noEscape */ $shuffle ?>"
     data-shuffle-weighted="<?= /* @noEscape */ $isWeightedRandom ?>">
    <?php endif; ?>
    <?php else:?>
    <div class="block <?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($class) ?>">
        <?php endif; ?>
        <div class="block-title title">
            <strong id="block-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($class) ?>-heading" role="heading"
                    aria-level="2"><?= $block->escapeHtml($title) ?></strong>
        </div>
        <div class="block-content content" aria-labelledby="block-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($class) ?>-heading">
            <?php if ($type == 'related' && $canItemsAddToCart):?>
                <div class="block-actions">
                    <?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Check items to add to the cart or')) ?>
                    <button type="button" class="action select"
                            data-role="select-all"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('select all')) ?></span></button>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
            <div class="products wrapper grid products-grid products-<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($type) ?>">
                <ol class="products list items product-items">
                    <?php foreach ($items as $_item):?>
                        <?php $available = ''; ?>
                        <?php if (!$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable() && $type == 'related'):?>
                            <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()):?>
                                <?php $available = 'related-available'; ?>
                            <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <?php if ($type == 'related' || $type == 'upsell'):?>
                            <li class="item product product-item"
                            id="product-item_<?= /* @noEscape */ $_item->getId() ?>"
                            data-shuffle-group="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getPriority()) ?>" >
                            <?= /* @noEscape */ $secureRenderer->renderStyleAsTag(
                                'display:none;',
                                'li#product-item_' . $_item->getId()
                            ) ?>
                        <?php else:?>
                            <li class="item product product-item">
                        <?php endif; ?>
                        <div class="product-item-info <?= /* @noEscape */ $available ?>">
                            <?= /* @noEscape */ '<!-- ' . $image . '-->' ?>
                            <a href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl($_item)) ?>"
                               class="product photo product-item-photo">
                                <?= $block->getImage($_item, $image)->toHtml() ?>
                            </a>
                            <div class="product details product-item-details">
                                <strong class="product name product-item-name"><a
                                            class="product-item-link"
                                            title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getName()) ?>"
                                            href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getProductUrl($_item)) ?>">
                                        <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getName()) ?></a>
                                </strong>
                                <?php if ($showAddTo) { ?>
                                      <?= $block->escapeHtml($_item->getSku() ?>
                                <?php } ?>

                                <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getProductPrice($_item) ?>

                                <?php if ($templateType):?>
                                    <?= $block->getReviewsSummaryHtml($_item, $templateType) ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php if ($canItemsAddToCart && !$_item->isComposite() && $_item->isSaleable()
                                    && $type == 'related'):?>
                                    <?php if (!$_item->getRequiredOptions()):?>
                                        <div class="field choice related">
                                            <input
                                                type="checkbox"
                                                class="checkbox related"
                                                id="related-checkbox<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>"
                                                name="related_products[]"
                                                value="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId()) ?>" />
                                            <label class="label"
                                                   for="related-checkbox<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getId())
                                                    ?>"><span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    <?php endif; ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>

                                <?php if ($showAddTo || $showCart):?>
                                    <?php // phpcs:disable ?>
                                    <div class="product actions product-item-actions">
                                        <?php if ($showCart):?>
                                            <div class="actions-primary">
                                            <?php if ($_item->isSaleable()):?>
                                                <?php if (!$_item->getTypeInstance()->isPossibleBuyFromList($_item)):?>
                                                    <button
                                                            class="action tocart primary"
                                                            data-mage-init='{"redirectUrl": {"url": "<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item)) ?>"}}' type="button" title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Cart')) ?>">
                                                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span>
                                                    </button>
                                                <?php else :?>
                                                    <?php
                                                    /** @var $viewModel PreparePostData */
                                                    $viewModel = $block->getViewModel();
                                                    $postArray = $viewModel->getPostData(
                                                        $block->escapeUrl($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item)),
                                                        ['product' => $_item->getEntityId()]
                                                    );
                                                    $value = $postArray['data'][ActionInterface::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED];
                                                    ?>
                                                    <form data-role="tocart-form"
                                                          data-product-sku="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr($_item->getSku()) ?>"
                                                          action="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getAddToCartUrl($_item)) ?>"
                                                          method="post">
                                                        <input type="hidden" name="product"
                                                               value="<?= /* @noEscape */ (int)$_item->getEntityId() ?>">
                                                        <input type="hidden"
                                                               name="<?= /* @noEscape */ ActionInterface::PARAM_NAME_URL_ENCODED?>"
                                                               value="<?= /* @noEscape */ $value ?>">
                                                        <?= $block->getBlockHtml('formkey') ?>
                                                        <button type="submit"
                                                                title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add to Cart')) ?>"
                                                                class="action tocart primary">
                                                            <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add to Cart')) ?></span>
                                                        </button>
                                                    </form>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            <?php else:?>
                                                <?php if ($_item->getIsSalable()):?>
                                                    <div class="stock available">
                                                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('In stock')) ?></span>
                                                    </div>
                                                <?php else:?>
                                                    <div class="stock unavailable">
                                                        <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Out of stock')) ?></span>
                                                    </div>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            <?php endif; ?>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>

                                        <?php if ($showAddTo):?>
                                            <div class="secondary-addto-links actions-secondary"
                                                 data-role="add-to-links">
                                                <?php if ($addToBlock = $block->getChildBlock('addto')):?>
                                                    <?= $addToBlock->setProduct($_item)->getChildHtml() ?>
                                                <?php endif; ?>
                                            </div>
                                        <?php endif; ?>
                                    </div>
                                    <?php // phpcs:enable ?>
                                <?php endif; ?>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        </li>
                    <?php endforeach ?>
                </ol>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <?php if (!$block->isRedirectToCartEnabled() && $_item):?>
        <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
            "[data-role=tocart-form], .form.map.checkout": {
                "catalogAddToCart": {
                    "product_sku": "<?= $block->escapeJs($_item->getSku()) ?>"
                }
            }
        }
        </script>
    <?php endif;?>
    <?php endif;?>
```

Comment: That was it! I would like to do the exact same thing in the grid template. Will the same code work?

Comment: if you are talking about the category listing template you then you will need to update the existing template and add in <?= $block->escapeHtml($_product->getSku()) ?>